# NuGet Packages will not install

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget

VS 2019 .NetCore 3.1

I regularly keep the NuGet packages upto date.  But for some reason, this time (all V5.0.0) fail to install.

It's saying they are not compatible.  I've not experienced this before.  Why is it listing the updates if they are not for .NET Core 3.1?   Are others experiencing this?
Also, it does seem a bit of a jump from 3.1.9 -> 5.0.0 when I am upgrading them about once a week.

[image]
[image]

Comment: As lan Kemp told you, [dotnet core 5](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0) is released 2 days ago and these nuget packages are compatible with new version of dotnet core (v5). So, if you like, you can immigrate to v5 as [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) explained how to.

Comment: It is a double question. Check these posts - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64792261/can-i-update-to-net-5-nuget-packages-even-if-im-using-net-core-3-1/64794340?noredirect=1#comment114561787_64794340

Comment: Check these posts too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64792261/can-i-update-to-net-5-nuget-packages-even-if-im-using-net-core-3-1/64794340?noredirect=1#comment114561787_64794340

Comment: Jab, Thank you.  I'll look at the article.

Comment: Sergey, I think those two were posted at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to .NET 5.0 (followed by updating the NuGet packages) fixed the issue.  In my case, it was simply a matter of replacing all:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

with:

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

throughout the whole of the solution.  Thanks for the heads up.