# Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly 5.0.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)

Tags: visual-studio-2019, blazor

I created a hosted WASM Blazor app using the Blazor client template in Visual Studio. I am trying to upgrade the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly package in the Client project from 3.2.1 to 5.0. I get this error:

Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly 5.0.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly 5.0.0 supports: net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)  BlazorApp1.Client

The client project is targeting .NET Standard 2.1. I am not clear about the difference between targeting .NET standard and targeting .Net Core. I thought .NET Core 5.0 implements all of .NET Standard 2.1. Only .NET Standard target options are available.

How does one upgrade that package?

Also, there's no version 5.0 of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build. Did the package get obsoleted?

Comment: Right-click the project, open properties, Go to the Application tab, change the Target Framework

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#update-blazor-webassembly-and-blazor-server-projects

Comment: @WalterVehoeven I SAID all the options are .NET standard and it's already targeting 2.1.

Comment: If you were confused by VS's notification of possible package updates, try to switch to `dotnet outdated` which is more reliable, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64925213/11182

Answer (score 2):

Although you can reference `netstandard2.1` packages in a .NET5 application (targeting `net5.0`), to upgrade your Blazor app to 5.0.0 (.NET5) you also have to change target framework to `net5.0` since it depends on it, as you have noticed.

But other than this, there are more changes to be made to get it fully upgraded. The MS Docs on how to [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 3.1 to 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#update-blazor-webassembly-and-blazor-server-projects) (as Brian already pointed out) should help get the job done.

Comment: Does this apply to class libraries as well? I have a class library that has reference to this DLL and won't upgrade: https://github.com/Postlagerkarte/blazor-dragdrop/issues/94

Comment: @HassanGulzar, correct. Remember - the purpose of .Net5 and forward is to consolidate .netcore and .netstandard to one cross-platform framework. And so, everything that is built now targets .net5.