# How to uninstall DevExpress from Visual Studio completely?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, devexpress, nuget-package-restore

I have installed DevExpress but now I uninstalled it. When I create a new project in Visual Studio 2022, then click on "build" and run, I get this error below. I guess Visual Studio is still searching for DevExpress files. I tried to remove all DevExpress extensions from Visual Studio, but that did not work. I tried also uninstall Visual Studio 2022 and reinstall it. How can I completely uninstall DevExpress from Visual Studio? Or is there an any method to clean visual studio to default settings?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMKOJ.png)

Comment: Suggest you ask this at devexpress.com

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55086195/the-resolvepackageassets-task-failed-unexpectedly) related question?

Comment: Have you tried to install visual studio on another directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you mentioned is related to the Package sources settings (Tools->Options-> type 'nuget'):
[image: Package sources options]
To avoid using unneeded sources you should follow the recommendations from the [Package Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources)  help article:

- To disable a package source, clear the box to the left of the name in the list.
- To remove a package source, select it and then select the X button.

Comment: I found the machine-wide DevExpress package source and it was unchecked already. I tried to remove it by using X button but whenever i click on the DevExpress package source option button was disabled. I solved the problem by deleting "C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config" folder. Thanks for the help.