# Blazor: ResolvePackageAssets task failed unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio, blazor

Not only a Blazor issue, appears to be a problem with Visual Studio. But I thought I'd repost from previous answers as they are all several years old, and it still happens with Blazor apps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly - System.TypeLoadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55086195/the-resolvepackageassets-task-failed-unexpectedly-system-typeloadexception)

Comment: Please do not repost question and answer pairs. If they helped you, upvote them. If you have anything to improve, post an answer on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to delete the projects 'bin' and/or 'obj' folders and rebuild, similar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55086195/the-resolvepackageassets-task-failed-unexpectedly-system-typeloadexception).